# How to stop connection in Netty when I got an error in my channelInboundHandler?

Tags: java, netty

Hello I am a newbie in Netty. After reading the documentation I found out that closing the channel can only be done in `ChannelOutboundHandler`. And I have tried to use close when I am in `ChannelInboundHandler` but to no avail the connection is not stopping and it's still processing all the handler.

Can anyone suggest to me the best way to close the tcp connection in netty when you are the server receiving request from client.

Answer (score 0):

You just call `ChannelHandlerContext.close()`. That said if there is pending inbound data it may still be fired through the pipeline